# Apache Cordova data beetwen page

Tags: ajax, cordova

i write an index.html page in cordova apache.
In this page I create a form for basic authentication. 
In this form I have a button and the click action have a binding with a ajax action in jquery. 
When ajax return success, I want to store login and pwd in two variabiles and pass it into a new page. 
How I can pass this data and read it into page2.html ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the variables into localStorage and access them in other pages:

```
window.localStorage.setItem("uname", username);
window.localStorage.setItem("pass", password);
```

Getting the values:

```
var uname = window.localStorage.getItem("uname") 
var pass = window.localStorage.getItem("pass");
```

Comment: Thanks.Only a question: for index.html page I have index.js where i bind my function. In newpage.html (where I will redirect), How I can get this value? I try to insert $( document ).ready(function(){... but It don't work.

Comment: There is a problem in my app. I insert code in deviceready, and work fine. Thanks